# which of internet devices has access to internet

Tags: internet-connection, network-adapter, ipconfig

I'm currently working on Intrusion Detection System, based on neural network.

The NN is already created, it is not the case.

Now, to use it, i need to write a program that gets information about flow of packets in PC.
Size of packet, lenght, rised flags etc. It doesnt realy matter.

Now, here is actual question.
I started with checking for active internet devices in my PC, and I discovered that i have 8.
I can get data that I need by scaning those devices, but do I realy have to scan all 8 of them?
I already checked that most of those devices are virtual, or inactive or whatever.
I assume that at least some of the devices are not important for me.

Below is a list of devices that my program finds in my PC.
My program will be working in pretty big company, and will be ran on multiple PCs, so please. Can you give me a clue, how to different important internet devices, from those not important, so I could write a program that different them automaticly.

I'll only say that 3rd connection (with IP 10.10...) is the actual internet connection (the one, that I assume is important).

Sorry if I didnt specify the problem properly, im begginer in all that network things :D

1) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{D662C0E3-611D-4AFE-ABDD-95411891793B}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 22

2) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{4F4F410E-0B14-427B-84C1-583BCB84FFCA}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 22

3) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{87F7D89B-320A-47E0-8330-1E13878238CB} 
FriendlyName: Wi-Fi

GatewayAddresses: 10.10.15.1

Description: Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::a9b6:335d:674a:8516

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      10.10.15.111

Netmask:   255.255.255.0

Broadaddr: 0.0.0.0

Addresses:

Addr:      HW addr: A8A79573F4F7

Flags: 30

4) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{7BC0AF4C-17D3-492C-88FC-AEE2BD3D05D0} 
FriendlyName: Połączenie lokalne* 3

Description: Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::6d11:5e52:2434:7a5e

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::6d11:5e52:2434:7a5e

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      HW addr: A8A79573F4F7

Flags: 46

5) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{9E0D4522-8B2D-4E6E-8F10-A869CD5934B8}
FriendlyName: Połączenie lokalne* 2

Description: Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::93c:79a7:e4a2:245b

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::93c:79a7:e4a2:245b

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      HW addr: AAA79573F4F7

Flags: 46

6) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{15F7CBE1-D9E6-4219-B941-DE28810CEA83}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 22

7) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{59953882-6AF2-4075-8E21-E803AC750846}
FriendlyName: Npcap Loopback Adapter

Description: Network adapter 'MS NDIS 6.0 LoopBack Driver' on local host

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::3d61:2c49:c88c:1aae

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      0.0.0.0

Netmask:   255.0.0.0

Broadaddr: 255.255.255.255

Addresses:

Addr:      HW addr: 02004C4F4F50

Flags: 22

8) interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{3FA9689C-61B4-4B57-8E0D-AFD90B9B55B1}
FriendlyName: Ethernet

Description: Network adapter 'Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller' on local host

Addresses:

Addr:      fe80::c92b:eee9:8467:8e89

Netmask:

Broadaddr:

Addresses:

Addr:      192.168.100.18

Netmask:   255.255.255.0

Broadaddr: 0.0.0.0

Addresses:

Addr:      HW addr: FC3FDB5E4B19

Flags: 38

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you need to know if your pc has access to the internet? If so, ping an internet address and see if you get a response. Do you know of a device has access to the network, see if they have an ip address. Although the 169.254.x.x is an active network that did not receive an ip address from a DHCP server, it is possible to setup an adhoc network this way and therefor should not be omitted, while it likely is not connected to anything.

Comment: Thank you for replay :) the list above is a list of active network devices in PC. I need to know, which of this devices i responsible for Internet Connection. I need to know how to recognize such device on any PC working with Windows. I can generate such a list on any PC, and sometime there will be 1 network device, sometime 20. I need to know which of those devices have access to internet, so my Intrusion Detecting System can track flow of packets through those devices. And im asking for clues how to recognize such devices.

Comment: Any device that has a gateway address listed as well (not in your list) will have internet access. But when a proxy server is in the mix, the gateway address may be left empty and internet can still be provided through the network.

Comment: That is a bad information. So, depending only on informations from that examples from mian post. Is there a way I can check with 100% accuracy that "this device has access to internet", or at least "this device doesnt have access to internet". Or maybe there is another way to check if device has access to internet. I need a clue, what factors determine access to internet. I can write other program to check them. As less factors as possible, to not overcomplicate live. But still i have to check this with 100% accuracy, due this is in fact a "firewall like" program.

Comment: I could always track all internet devices at the same time, but this is something I realy want to avoid. If pc would have like 50 network devices or more, keeping track on all of them will be troublesome.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered any more than I just did. You can check if a pc has access to the internet by simply pinging to a server located on the internet. But to determine what devices make the connection depends on so many factors. It is possible to have a LAN connection and a WIFI connection active at the same time that both provide internet access. A VPN connection can provide a 3rd source of internet access even and all 3 connections will have the same information where all 3 connections may not actually be the device that provides internet.

Comment: You can attempt a traceroute to the internet and follow the ip trail to see which device is responsible for that internet call. But that doesn't mean you have all devices that provide access to the internet. You just get one. Given the discussion we have going on, I'm going to suggest that this gets closed as too broad, because this really is too broad.

Comment: Ok, i understand.
thank you for your time :).

I think I have no other choice than to scan all devices then.